# Dialog shows behind parent in Windows 10 Tablet Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, windows-10

I have a Winforms application with a form that shows a dialog:

```
using (MyForm form = new MyForm)) {
   form.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

The dialog being shown has the following properties:

```
StartPosition = CenterParent
ControlBox = True
MaximizeBox = True
MinimizeBox = True
FormBorderStyle = Sizable
```

Normally, the form displays modally on top of the calling form. However, when running in Windows 10 in Tablet Mode (like on a Surface Pro 3 with the keyboard removed), the form shows behind the calling form and there's no way to get to it because everything is full screen.

Is there any setting I can change to prevent this behavior (other than telling the user to not use Tablet Mode)?

Comment: Here's an untested wild stab at a workaround--add the following code to the dialog class's `Load` event handler: `BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.Activate()));`  (where `this` is the dialog instance, so add the handler to the `MyForm` class, not the calling class)

Comment: @adv12: Good thought. Gave it a shot but it made no difference.

Comment: Bummer!  That was my best guess.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is dumb.  I took a look at another form being shown as a dialog that actually works. The difference:

```
MaximizeBox = False
```

Once you remove the ability to maximize the form, it shows as you would expect. The funny thing is it was never necessary to be able to maximize the form; it just got left with the default value.

Comment: What if I wanted the new window to be maximizable as well?

Comment: In my situation, the dialogs don't need to be maximized, so I have no idea.

Comment: The dialog is opened in the background even without maximized button.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else stumbles upon this question looking for a solution to that same problem in WPF:

Specifying **ShowInTaskbar="False"** on dialogs worked for me.